# Windows Phone Soap/Add Web Reference issues

Tags: soap, windows-phone-7

I've got a SOAP (powered by Java) service I'm trying to hook up to WP7. 
Using `Add -> Service Reference` generates the proxy client, but unfortunately drops all the parameters to the methods on both WP7 and "full" .NET 4. Same result using slsvcutil.exe. ie, service.Login(string, string) becomes service.Login() (or BeginLogin() for WP7)

Using `Add -> Web Reference` on .NET 4 works a treat, and the service is fine, but this option is greyed out completely in WP7.

There are hundreds of errors when parsing the file through svcutil, all along the lines of

> Warning: The optional WSDL extension
>   element 'fault' from namespace
>   'http://sche
>   mas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' was not
>   handled.

In this particular case I *can't* proxy it through another webservice, nor can I really modify the WSDL/service generating the WSDL

Are there any workarounds for auto-generated client proxy for SOAP services on WP7?

Answer (score 1):

The solution form Muhimbi is working. Just add a new phone class project. And add the web reference.

It seems that this occurs when you use the full VS 2010 version in stead of the VS phone edition.

Michel

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is exactly the same, but I got a similar problem, which I think is related to the fact that I am using the 'full' VS2010 rather than the one that comes with the WP7 SDK.

What I ended up doing was adding a separate project to the solution and add the service reference to that project.