# How to call Java soap Services In Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a Windows Phone 7  application .  My Requirement  is to use Java soap services to read the data saved in database. But am not able to read the data as am getting null values by using Java Services.Please help me
Thanks in Advance

Comment: SOAP is platform independent. It does not matter at all which language the SOAP services are written in. So google for "windows phone 7 soap"

Answer (score 0):

You can just use "eval" to invoke the Javacode you need in WebBrowser Control.

Here is the information example which helped me in that case:
http://timoboehme.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/java-code-auf-dem-windows-phone-ausfhren/

[image: Eval WP7 script]

Comment: Hi Nasenbaer,Thank you for your Reply.But i want to  call the java soap service in wp7 not the javascript can you help me in that ..

Comment: I am sorry. For soap service, I read two articles. One said, Visual Studio 2010 Express need to be updated to Visual Studio full version to work with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209974/windows-phone-soap-add-web-reference-issues. Other article said, there is a need for cretitals. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/316d80b7-9c66-4403-b5a9-0bf7c752fed4